# How to adjust trim potentiometer

Tags: hardware

I bought some DC-DC buck converters which are supposedly adjustable.

They have a tiny trim potentiometer on them, but how are those adjusted? I tried my tinyest screwdriver, but it simply won't turn.

I tried on all 5 of them, and tried 10 different screwdrivers, this has me puzzled
[image]

Comment: Just rotate it with a screwdriver. Didn't it come with a manual? Why not ask the seller?

Comment: Note that some trim pots are used to *permanently* set maximum current or voltage values. One set the MFG will glue it with epoxy so it can never be adjusted. However this speck of glue is very obvious, often red or white in color.

Comment: @Justme it's just a anonymous Chinese ebay reseller, so I don't expect a lot of support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a small Philips screwdriver. The cross is clearly visible in your photo.

[image]

Comment: Ok I'll try again, is it supposed to turn only 1 circle or can it turn indefinitely? The pot is so shallow that a regular philips won't fit because it doesn't go deep enough for it to pick up the cross..

Comment: The resistance track should be about 300°. I can't see whether or not there are end-stops on that potentiometer. You should be able to use the slot-head screwdriver of the correct width. It won't slip out of the slots.

Comment: So I modified a small flat head and filed it down to fit the slot, I can turn it now. It looks like the track is very small only. I am supplying it with 5v and I can only get it to 3.8v or 1.8, no way to get it to 3.3v. I think that the resolution of the pot meter is way too small as it accepts an input of 0.9v-30v it's hard to make very small adjustments. Even by not touching the pot it keeps jumping 0.2v up and down.

Comment: Grip the screwdriver shaft with a vise-grip to act as a long lever. You'll be able to get much more precision with your adjustment. The alternative is to desolder the pot and use a larger one of the same value with a knob.